# Fortran runtime error: Constant string in input format

Tags: linux, string, ubuntu, runtime-error, gfortran

When i tried to calculate elastic constant using IRelast. i was getting error below in my WIEN2k 19.2 package installed in my workstation with ubuntu OS. Below is the error message i am gettting while running the command 'set_elast_pressure'.

```
 E=E0+[B*V/BP*(1/(BP-1)*(V0/V)**BP +1)-B*V0/(BP-1)]

 E
 Read data from line 8 ....
At line 83 of file calLa_Pre_elast.f (unit = 10, file = 'MgO.outputeos')
Fortran runtime error: Constant string in input format
(' V0,B(GPa),BP,E0',3f15.4,f18.6)
                                ^

Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x154aa00e932a
#1  0x154aa00e9ed5
#2  0x154aa00ea69d
#3  0x154aa0253cb1
#4  0x154aa0262101
#5  0x154aa026372c
#6  0x154aa02642d2
#7  0x55d47934d7ef
#8  0x55d47934cd7e
#9  0x154a9f960c86
#10  0x55d47934cdb9
#11  0xffffffffffffffff
cp: cannot stat 'init.struct': No such file or directory


   (C)by Morteza Jamal   
         (2014)     
   *****  * *      ******
     *    *   *    *
     *    * *      ******
     *    * *      *
   *****  *   *    ******


#######################################
#          set_elast_lapw          

#######################################
#     C_set_elast_lapw prepares       #
#    Directories  and job files.      #
#     C(2017) by Morteza Jamal        #
#      it creates   c11+2c12,         #
#       c11-c12, and c44 directories  #
#       and CUBIC.job file            #
#             in them                 #
#      which must be executed         #
#      and can be analyzed by         #
#         C_ana_elast_lapw            #
#######################################
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '../../MgO/.'
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '../../MgO/..'
```

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Use relevant debugging flags such as `gfortran -g -fcheck=all -Wall`. Please be aware that this is a programming site, not a support site for your software. The code and the necessary data is necessary. Show the line referenced in the error message and the relevant surrounding. See [ask] and [mcve].